# How frequent is it for governments to win votes in the house of Commons, which would fail without the backing of the opposition?

Tags: united-kingdom, parliament

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_government_defeats_in_the_House_of_Commons_(1945%E2%80%93present)

This is a list of government defeats in the house of Commons. Does a similar list exist for how many times governments have won votes, but which they would have lost without opposition support?

Example: 2006 Education and Inspections Act, which only passed with Conservative support.

Comment: @ohwilleke: note that one of the jobs of government whips is to get a sense of the mood of MPs. If it seems likely that the government might lose a vote, they may try to avoid the vote taking place. For example, if a proposed legislative amendment is likely to lose, the government may opt to withdraw it, or propose a different one, etc. Much of this happens behind the scenes, and before any schedules or amendments, etc, are published, so you don't see it. But it does help to explain why government defeats are so uncommon.

Comment: Yep. This is also likely why it's uncommon for them to win votes where Opposition support is nontrivial wrt to winning the vote.

Comment: Just to note that it’s quite likely to happen next Tuesday when the new Covid restrictions are voted on, which I assume is why you’re asking this question now.

Comment: Agreed, that's the inspiration for question, decided not to put it in unless it actually happens that way

Comment: Would you include votes on issues which the Government supports, but allows its MPs a free vote on? E.g. the vote on the [Abortion (Northern Ireland) Regulations 2021](https://www.publicwhip.org.uk/division.php?date=2021-04-27&number=280&house=commons)?

Comment: No, I'm thinking of votes where the government whips the vote, and wins it, but would have lost if not for opposition support.